# Oauth HMac Signature Generator for HERE map

Tags: authentication, here-maps-rest, oauth-1.0a

I want to use HERE map api's in my project.

As per their document, I need to use generate the signature first using Oauth 1.0 HMAC-256.

I am following below AAA sdk by HERE map :
https://github.com/heremaps/here-aaa-java-sdk/blob/master/here-oauth-client/src/main/java/com/here/account/auth/SignatureCalculator.java

```
SignatureCalculator signatureCalculator = new SignatureCalculator(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET);
String signature = signatureCalculator.calculateSignature("GET","https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token",
(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L),RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(12), 
SignatureMethod.HMACSHA256,null,null);
```

But I am not able to generate the token using this signature. I got below error :

> {"errorId":"ERROR-25b51579-57d0-4873-b82e-466519b8b6a4","httpStatus":401,"errorCode":401202,"message":"Invalid Client Authorization header, expecting signed request format.","error":"invalid_request","error_description":"errorCode: '401202'. Invalid Client Authorization header, expecting signed request format."}

When i try to do same through postman then everything works perfect.
There is difference between both the signature (generated though postman which works / generated though java code)

pw7d5IVYFsYH0zNPNZJU7x3T6LUtDj8zzYw2hsUUlM= .  -- Not Working. Generated using AAA here library.
tBWyomfDmgihh2kC%2B14qYurOoPF%2FYkpg7QyGpwgZ77A%3D"  -- Working Signature , generated through postman

I think I am doing wrong signature generation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to done signature encoding by URLEncoding in UTF-8 format.

```
URLEncoder.encode("Signature_Generated_from_HMAC-SHA256","UTF-8")
```